# how to check the emptyness of a textbox in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i have a gridview with 2 fields property,values and contains 3 textboxes.
    when i enter the values,i kept some textboxes as empty,i need to check that empty     textboxes.And that empty values don't want to insert into database. How can  i solve this  problem???

This is my code

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
  string strcon1;
  strcon1 =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fwma_devConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

  SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strcon1);
  con1.Open();

  SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand(strcon);

  TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("TextBox2");//value

  string txt = tb.Text;

  Label propertylabel = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label4");//id-property

  com3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BrandProperties(PropertyID,BrandID,[Values]) values('" + propertylabel.Text + "','" + B_id.Text + "','" + tb.Text + "')";
  com3.Connection = con1;
  com3.ExecuteNonQuery();

  con1.Close();

  if (tb.Text == String.Empty)
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to show some warning when this is empty? Or just abort the insertion?

Comment: just want to abort that empty textbox insertion.Don't want to show any warnings.

Comment: Try to check for `null` or `Empty` before insert query, Not after `insert` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reorganize you code to first get the textbox control, then check for a non-empty string.  If non-empty, then do the DB insert.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
  TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("TextBox2");//value

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text))
  {
     string strcon1;
     strcon1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["fwma_devConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

     SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strcon1);
     con1.Open();

     SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand(strcon);

     Label propertylabel = (Label)gvr.FindControl("Label4");//id-property

     com3.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BrandProperties(PropertyID,BrandID,[Values]) values('" + propertylabel.Text + "','" + B_id.Text + "','" + tb.Text + "')";
     com3.Connection = con1;
     com3.ExecuteNonQuery();

     con1.Close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this ok ?

//Code

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("TextBox2");//value
string txt = tb.Text;
If(tb.Text!=string.IsNullOrEmpty)
{
  //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Just one tip! Use string.IsNullOrEmpty for this kind of comparassion!

Comment: inserting the same blank row in database.

Comment: Debug the value of textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You may try for

```
If(tb.Text!= string.Empty)
{
  //Do your stuff
}
```

Or

```
If(tb.Text!="")
{
  //Do your stuff
}
```

Or, Try to check for `null` or `Empty` before `insert` query.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty("tb.Text"))
{
  // Do Your stuff
}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: same.. :( inserting the blank textbox  in database row

Comment: yes it will add blank because you are running `insert` query before `null` check..

Answer (score 1):

Best Idea is use required field validator for that textbox. Then you can add double checking like

> string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text)